# how do get metadata of a website to show link preview?

Tags: javascript

I want to get metadata (`title`, `description` etc) of a website to show link preview in my chat application.

My plan is to get the `webpage` of the website using `link` (by `XHR` request from my app) and parse it to get metadata. (I want to do everything in browser without needing to contact server for the purposes of link preview)

But in most of the case I get `CORS`.

**My question is:**

How do I get around `CORS` to get a website's main page? If its not possible, how do other chat application implement link preview? Do they all require a server for that?

Comment: "How do I get around CORS to get a website's main page?" — See the duplicate.

Comment: "Do they all require a server for that?" — Using a server *is* getting around the lack of CORS.

Comment: @Quentin I know you use server to get around cors. But this question is about link preview. Maybe I am not thinking in right direction? Just need some guidance how other people implement link preview. Thanks.

Comment: "But this question is about link preview" — And you want to do that by reading data from the website, which you don't have permission to do from the browser, so you need to do it on the server.

Comment: ok. Thanks you.